# How can I get Data Using Reporting Service from DB2

Tags: reporting-services, db2, oledb, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

How can I get data from db2 by using Reporting Service?
1.I installed MS OLE DB provider for db2,and got the connectionstring , Test OK.
2.I add a new datasource ds1 in SSRS connection Type is OLE DB, and input the connectionstring , connecting successed .
3.Open report Builder and use ds1 ,connecting successed .
4.But When I create a DataSet by using ds1,I can not get data using any format SQL.
for example:
`select a from table1;`
`select a from library.table1;`
`select a from schema.library.table1;`

It always popup error message  DB_E_ERRORSINCOMMAND(0x80040E14)

I think maybe I input wrong SQL , But what is the right format?

this is conntionstring.
 `Provider=DB2OLEDB;User ID=xx;Password=xx;Initial Catalog=TEST;Network Transport  Library=TCPIP;Host CCSID=5026;PC Code Page=932;Network Address=111.111.111.111;Network  Port=446;Default Schema=aaa;Units of Work=RUW;DBMS Platform=DB2/AS400;Use Early  Metadata=False;Defer Prepare=False;DateTime As Char=False;Rowset Cache Size=0;Binary      CodePage=0;Datetime As Date=False;AutoCommit=True;Database  Name=Test;Authentication=Server;Decimal As Numeric=False;Allow Null  Chars=False;LoadBalancing=False;Persist Security Info=True;Cache  Authentication=False;Connection Pooling=False;Literal Replacement=False;`